# Create function HSQLDB user lacks privilage or object not found

Tags: hsqldb

I try to create a function (or routine) in hsqldb to concatante field values, basicly an alias doing the same thing as GROUP_CONCAT with a different name and signature.

So i wrote it like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION STRING_AGG(field VARCHAR(1000), nothing VARCHAR(1))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
   RETURN GROUP_CONCAT(field)
```

and it says **user lacks privilage or object not found: FIELD**
tried to look in the documentation or on other threads on function creation but has not found anything that helps.

Comment: I've seen the example on hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/guide.html with group_concatenate, but when i try to modify that to add a second parameter it says that the signature for aggregate function is wrong. so i don't see how i call it with 2 parameters (the field and the useless ',' part)

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT is an aggregate function and cannot be used outside a SELECT statement.

As your comment shows, HyperSQL allows you to define new aggregate functions but it does not allow extra, non-aggregated, parameters.

As STRING_AGG is used in PostgreSQL and SQL Server, the function is now supported by HyperSQL. You need to check out the latest /trunk code from SVN and build the jar (see http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/building-app.html).